# How do I get 2 radio button selections to show 1 div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a development issue with jQuery script. I've tried to find something to re-purpose but have not been able to find exactly what I need. So I took a stab at writing something but have yet to get it to work correctly and I'm such a novice that I cannot seem to figure it out.

I am trying to get 2 radio buttons (first grouping of 3, second grouping of 2) to return 1 of 6 div tags on selection of both radio buttons.

I only wrote enough script for just clinical with either sales or support options.

html:

```
<div class="input-quest">Question 1</div>
<div id="optSelectBU">
    <input type="radio" name="button1" value="clinical" />
    <label>Clinical</label>
    <input type="radio" name="button1" value="financial" />
    <label>Financial</label>
    <input type="radio" name="button1" value="pharmacy" />
    <label>Pharmacy</label>
</div>
<div class="input-quest">Question 2</div>
<div id="optSelectService">
    <input type="radio" name="button2" value="support" />
    <label>Support</label>
    <input type="radio" name="button2" value="sales" />
    <label>Sales</label>
</div>
<div id="Clinical-Support">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Div 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Clinical-Sales">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Div 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Financial-Support">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Div 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Financial-Sales">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Div 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Pharmacy-Support">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Div 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Pharmacy-Sales">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">Div 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Clinical-Support").hide();
    $("#Clinical-Sales").hide();
    $("#Financial-Support").hide();
    $("#Financial-Sales").hide();
    $("#Pharmacy-Support").hide();
    $("#Pharmacy-Sales").hide();

    $("#optSelectBU").change(function () {
        if ($('input[name=button1]').val() == "clinical" && $('input[name=button2]').val() == "sales") {
            $("#Clinical-Sales").show();
        } else {
            $("#Clinical-Support").hide();
            $("#Clinical-Sales").hide();
            $("#Financial-Support").hide();
            $("#Financial-Sales").hide();
            $("#Pharmacy-Support").hide();
            $("#Pharmacy-Sales").hide();
        }
    });
    $("#optSelectBU").change(function () {
        if ($('input[name=button1]').val() == "clinical" && $('input[name=button2]').val() == "support") {
            $("#Clinical-Support").show();
        } else {
            $("#Clinical-Support").hide();
            $("#Clinical-Sales").hide();
            $("#Financial-Support").hide();
            $("#Financial-Sales").hide();
            $("#Pharmacy-Support").hide();
            $("#Pharmacy-Sales").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/schoward30506/LV5nQ/3/

Comment: It surely helps if you set the jQuery and head in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tq2LF/

Comment: man, this code is a mess. one hint: in the "change" function, you are not checking for the element, that just has been clicked. you are checking for the element <input name="button1">. you agree with me, that you have three of those buttons, right? jQuery just delivers you the first of these elements. cause you select it like that. the result is always clinical, cause its the first element and jQuery is happy (and working properly) with that.

Comment: Thanks so much. Believe me I probably had it right at one time, I was looking at so many codes and trying to use what was already written and just fiddling around i probably overwrote what was actually correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not pretty, but if you use `data-attributes` rather than the `id` then you could simplify your code massively:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("div[data-cats]").hide();    
    $("input[name=button1], input[name=button2]").change(function () {
        var b1 = $('input[name=button1]:checked').val();
        var b2 = $('input[name=button2]:checked').val();
        $("div[data-cats]").hide();        
        $("div[data-cats='"+b1+" "+b2+"']").show();       
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LV5nQ/6/

Comment: You are a lifesaver. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

i fiddled around and came to this solution.
please keep in mind, that i added a div#container around your changing divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/LV5nQ/10/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#container > div").hide();

var input1, input2;

function checkboxChecker() {
    if ( input1 === "clinical" && input2 === "sales" ) {
        $("#Clinical-Sales").show().siblings("div").hide();
    } else if ( input1 === "clinical" && input2 === "support" ) {
        $("#Clinical-Support").show().siblings("div").hide();
    } else {
        $("#container > div").hide();
    }
};

$("input[name=button1], input[name=button2]").change(function () {
    input1 = $('input[name=button1]:checked').val();
    input2 = $('input[name=button2]:checked').val();
    checkboxChecker();
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much you, this has been killing me.